# How to solve $v f^{'}_v + f = 0$, $f(0, y) = y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I was presented with this equation in my textbook, currently studying multi variable calculus:

$$yf^{'}_x(x,y) - xf^{'}_y(x,y) = f(x,y)$$

Using the substitution:

$$x^2 + y^2 = u$$
$$e^{{-x^2}{/2}} = v$$

I get the equation (which is correct):

$$v f^{'}_v + f = 0$$

My next task is to find the solution, $f(x,y)$ that satisfies $f(0, y) = y^2$. The correct answer should be $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)e^{{-x^2}{/2}}$.

But here I am stuck, I have solved similar tasks but I don't know how to handle the $f$. For example $v f^{'}_v = x$ or similar would be easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the left-hand side equals $(v f)'_v$ (derivative of a product).

Comment: Thank you, not sure exactly how you mean, if you have time I would love a bit more explanation :)

Comment: I assume you know the product rule $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ from single-variable calculus, right? Just apply that to the product $v \cdot f(u,v)$ with the partial derivative $\partial/\partial v$ instead of the ordinary derivative. It works the same, since the partial derivative *is* just an ordinary derivative once you have fixed a value of $u$.

Comment: And you have also probably seen how to solve first-order ordinary differential equations using an integrating factor? This is the same type of problem.